# Is there any way to improve the speed of reading a text file in Python?

Tags: python, performance, file

I am reading a file of 587 kb which contains words from a-z like:
aa
bb
cc
...and so on...
Now, no matter what code I write, it literally takes 38 seconds to read the file!

```
with open('dictionary.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as dictionary:
      dictionary.read().splitlines()
```

My question is: How can I read the file in less than at least 4 seconds? Also, it must return all the words in a list.

---

*The problem has been solved*
"I got it! Instead of being only in the problem and selecting a random word, I was printing all the words instead, silly me. And now when I am doing this, it's giving me the word in a fraction of a second: pastie.org/8149529 "

Comment: Can you provide the file on PasteBin? 38 seconds sounds incredibly slow to read such a small file.

Comment: Is this the complete script that you timed? A snippet like that should not take that long on any reasonable hardware.

Comment: The question asks about the speed of reading a file, but have you considered the possibility that it's not the speed of reading the file per se, but the speed of the code that is processing the file? You might want to make the title of your question a bit more accurate.

Comment: You mentioned you're using IDLE.  I suspect that the delay you're seeing isn't the time it takes to read the file, but is actually the time to *print* it.  Could you try timing `words = dictionary.read().splitlines()` and then `print len(words)`?

Comment: 58110
Got the message instantly, but it's again taking forever to print the list of words.

Comment: OP's comment on my answer: "All right, thanks everyone. I got it! Instead of being only in the problem and selecting a random word, I was printing all the words instead, silly me. And now when I am doing this, it's giving me the word in a fraction of a second" We can close this question, or the OP can delete it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should require less memory because it iterates over lines:

```
words = []
with open('dictionary.txt', encoding='utf-8') as dictionary:
    for line in dictionary:
        words.extend(line.split())
```

Comment: `readlines()` returns an array of all the lines.  In order to save the memory you're talking about, you'd have to do `for line in dictionary:`

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: You are totally right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get all the words in a file:

```
>>> with open('dictionary.txt', encoding='utf-8') as dictionary:
    words = dictionary.read().split()
```

Comment: I think he has one word per line

Comment: The result is the same regardless.

Comment: All right, thanks everyone. I got it!
Instead of being only in the problem and selecting a random word, I was printing all the words instead, silly me. And now when I am doing this, it's giving me the word in a fraction of a second:
http://pastie.org/8149529

Comment: @Akshat: Perhaps then you should delete your question...or at least modify it so people don't have read all the way down to your comment here to understand it was all a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('dictionary.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as dictionary:
     list(dictionary)
```

maybe??? if it takes that long im curious what your specs are

can you post the results

```
import time
s = time.time()
with open('dictionary.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as dictionary:
     x=list(dictionary)
print time.time()-s
```

Comment: This will get the lines of the file, the OP clearly asked for all the words.

Comment: im pretty sure he has one word per line

Comment: I am using Windows 7 with Intel core i5 processor and 4 GB DDR3 RAM.

Comment: Also, I ran this using the IDLE, that might've affected something?
OK, I used the code suggested by @Jordan and I got this:
0.380000114441
Still, when I removed the time.time()-s and py 'print(x)' it took forever to display the result.

Comment: updated answer can you post the results? theres no way that machine should be that slow (38secs) is a loooong time

Answer (score 0):

The `read()` is reading the whole file into a string, then splitting the lines by copying the data.

Streaming the data by lines will help:

```
with open( 'dictionary.txt', .... ) as dictionary:
    for line in dictionary:
         <do something with the line>
```

Is the file structured as one word per line?
If it's not, then the  might be more splitting.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your snippet on [a 4 MB text file](http://svn.pietdepsi.com/repos/projects/zyzzyva/trunk/data/words/North-American/OWL.txt) and it took about half a second on my laptop with OS X. It did print the entire file out (surprisingly quickly), and on Windows I expect that would be really slow. Try saving the result to a variable so it doesn't print it:

```
with open('dictionary.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as dictionary:
    lines = dictionary.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "Got the message instantly, but it's again taking forever to print the list of words."

Accordingly, the problem your question poses does not exist. Keep using the code you have posted, and realise that printing to a console takes time, especially if you print line by line, rather than than preserving/creating linebreaks and printing at one time.